# what does the author (Mario Puzo) mean by the following sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, literature

What does the author (Mario Puzo) mean by the following sentence from *The Godfather*?

> There was no greater natural advantage in life than having an enemy overestimate your faults unless it was to have a friend underestimate your virtues.

It comes from the following passage:

> The Don considered a use of threats the most foolish kind of exposure; the unleashing of anger without forethought as the most dangerous indulgence. No one had ever heard the Don utter a naked threat, no one had ever seen him in an uncontrollable rage. It was unthinkable. And so he tried to teach Sonny his own disciplines. **He claimed that there was no greater natural advantage in life than having an enemy overestimate your faults, unless it was to have a friend underestimate your virtues.**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a literature criticism question, it's not really asking about the meaning but the *interpretation* of the sentence.

Comment: I thinmk this is a perfectly valid question for ELL. If closed on that ground, I will probably reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

The Don is saying that if an enemy thinks you are less capable than you are, by thinking your faults are larger than they actually are, it is a great advantage. He also says that if a friend thinks you less able or less good than you are, this is also an advantage. He uses a parallel construction to express these two thoughts. The parallel construction contrasts "enemy" with "friend", "faults" with "virtues", and "overestimate" with "underestimate".

In fact he is saying that having both friends and enemies think less of you then is accurate, although in different ways, is a good thing. Exactly which faults and which virtues the Don refers to is not stated, so it suggests all possible faults and virtues in general.

That the sentence starts with "He claimed" indicates that the narrator does not endorse this idea, and perhaps implies that it is not true.

Comment: thank you for your thought out response. im wondering if he also meant, your friends underestimating your virtues is a greater advantage than your enemy overestimating your faults.

Comment: @learnedlizard  The "unless" suggests uncertainty about which advantage is greater, but the Don says that the two are bigger than any others.

Comment: He claimed that there was no greater natural advantage in life than having an enemy overestimate your faults unless it was to have a friend underestimate your virtues.

what do you think that 'it' is referring to?

Comment: @learnedlizard "It" here means "natural advantage".  Compare "There is nothing sweeter than chocolate unless it is ice cream". This says that either chocolate  or  ice cream is the sweetest thing, but the speaker isn't sure which. This use of it is part of a common pattern, and is worth its own question.

Comment: thank you so much, cheers

Comment: _"That the sentence starts with "He claimed" indicates that the narrator does not endorse this idea"_ Galileo claimed that the Earth orbits the sun. This statement does not imply that I disagree with Galileo.

Comment: "Unless" does not express uncertainty here. It overrides the previous statement by adding an exception. E.g. "I always get out of bed at 6 am, unless it is Sunday". This is a statement of fact. Compare this to "I should get up, unless it's Sunday". This is not a statement of fact, and _does_ convey uncertainty. However, OP's quote is the former, i.e. an absolute statement of fact. 'Unless' is being used to add an exception to the earlier statement, not to introduce an uncertainty. Uncertainty would be introduced by using "unless perhaps", where _"perhaps"_ is the word indicating uncertaintly.

Comment: @Flater "Unless" can be used in that way, to state an exception. But that is not how it is being used here. "A is best, unless B is" says that either A or B is best, but the speaker is not sure which. That is the way "unless" is being used here. A similar meaning could be expressed with "perhaps" but that is not the only way to show uncertainty. The statements in your comment do not follow this pattern. Consider "I will go walking, unless I decide to fish". The speaker is not sure what decision s/he will make, but it will be one of two choices.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: _"A is best, unless B is"_ is not the same as "There is nothing better than A, unless it is B". The former questions whether B is better, whereas the latter does not. The latter states **definitively** that B is better than A. The only arguable uncertainty is whether "it" is A, B, or neither; but that's actually besides the point the author is making here. "The medal you're going to give me could not be better than silver, unless it is gold" is uncertain about what medal you're going to give me, but it is definitively stating that gold is better than silver.

Comment: @Flater I am sorry, But I am convinced you are mistaken here. "There is nothing better than A, unless it is B". is saying that either A or B is best, but is **not** asserting that B is better than A. It could be rephrased using "perhaps" or "maybe" and the meaning would be unchanged.  "There is nothing better than A, or maybe B" carries the same meaning. I have seen this use of "unless" on quite a few occasions, but mostly in older works, or in historical fiction, imitating the speech of an earlier time. But I believe that it is still valid, although perhaps less common than it once was. [...]

Comment: @DavidSiegel: I mean, it's literally in the [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/unless): _"used to give the only situation in which something will not happen or be true"_. While this often adds an uncertainty, that is not inherently the case. The first example (I sleep with the window open unless it's really cold) is in no way uncertain that the window will not be open when it is cold. You're confusing the uncertainty that it will be cold (on a given night) with the uncertainty that the speaker might sleep with the windows open on a cold night.

Comment: [..] The latter uncertainty is an incorrect reading of the example sentence provided. The former uncertainty is a correct reading, but when applied to OP's quote, is irrelevant to the meaning that is being conveyed. The quote provided by OP is only interested in making a generalized statement that B is greater than A (and that A and B together are the greatest advantages). It is not interested in stating that a particular advantage might be A or might be B.

Comment: @Flater "Unless" like many words, can be used in several ways. Yes, in the sentence about windows, it is listing an exception, and there is no uncertainty indicated. But consider the 3rd example sentence the def you link. It starts with "Unless I'm mistaken" The speaker is unsure if s/he is correct (albeit not very unsure) or the 4th "*He hasn't got any hobbies—unless you call watching TV a hobby.*" It could be put that the speaker is unsure if watching TV is a hobby. Neithre of these is quite like the example from Pujo, and there are other senses of "unless".

Comment: @DavidSiegel:  There are other definitions of "unless" but that does not mean that it inherently cannot be known which definition is being used in this particular example. The quote provided by OP does not convey uncertainty, it conveys an exception. It boils down to "There is nothing better than A, except B". B is the best, A is second best. That is what the sentence conveys.

Comment: @Flater To be clear, i am **not** asserting that 'unless" always indicates uncertainty. It often does not. But in some cases it does, and i am convinced that this is the case in the Pujo sentence.

Comment: @Flater I am afraid we must agree to disagree. "There is nothing better than A, except B" is subtly but significantly different in meaning from "There is nothing better than A, unless it is B"

Answer (score 1):

David Siegel's answer is good but I disagree with his interpretation of "unless" and what meaning it conveys.

The generalized sentence structure here is:

> There is no better [descriptor] than [awesome thing], unless [even more awesome thing].

You might wonder why the speaker would even bother mentioning [awesome thing], only to immediately override it by mentioning [even more awesome thing]. There's a few possibilities here:

- Maybe the speaker forgot about [even more awesome thing] and remembered midway through speaking, therefore amending his sentence.
- The speaker may have assumed that [even more awesome thing] wasn't available or a long shot, and therefore mentioned something more feasible as a fallback option.

  - This doesn't quite apply to your case. But it is a possible explanation, e.g. *"I'd love to have a cup of tea, unless you still happen to have some of that rare scotch?"*
- The speaker may have intended to mention both things and rank them, and they chose this phrasing because it mentions the second best thing before the best thing

  - Compare this to "scotch is better than tea". Comparatives tend to introduce the best thing first.
  - You could say "tea is worse than scotch" so you keep the best thing for last, but then you are implying a negative connotation, and in your example the speaker clearly intended to speak highly positively about both things.

So when you commented the following:

> I'm wondering if he also meant your friends underestimating your virtues is a greater advantage than your enemy overestimating your faults.

You are exactly right. The phrase expresses that both are great advantages, but then goes on to point out that friends underestimating your virtues is even bigger of an advantage.